# Excel VBA - Button to find information between workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a beginner at VBA and I'm trying to create a button to search for previous data inserted in all workbooks, using information as client name or date [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77D8r.jpg). Could you help me with some tips? I attached my code until now below. Thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub data_consulta_Change()
    If VBA.Len(data_consulta.Text) = 2 Then
        data_consulta = data_consulta + "/"
    End If

    If VBA.Len(data_consulta.Text) = 5 Then
        data_consulta = data_consulta + "/"
    End If
End Sub
```

```
Private Sub limpar_Click()
    cliente_nome = ""
    data_consulta = ""
End Sub
```

```
Private Sub pesquisar_base_Click()

On Error GoTo Erro
'Dim pesquisa As String
'pesquisa = InputBox("Digite as informações da consulta!", "PESQUISAR")

Dim linha As Double
linha = 1

With Planilha1    
    Do   
        linha = linha + 1
        If .Cells(linha, 2).Value = pesquisa Or .Cells(linha, 3).Value Or .Cells(linha, 4).Value Then            
            data_consulta = .Cells(linha, 2).Value
            data_consulta = .Cells(linha, 4).Value        
            Exit Sub        
        End If
    Loop Until .Cells(linha, 2).Value = ""    
    MsgBox "Informação não encontrada!", vbInformation, "PESQUISA" 
End With

Exit Sub
Erro:
    MsgBox "Digite as informações da consulta!", cvcritical, "ERRO"

End Sub
```

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    data_consulta = VBA.Date
End Sub

'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    '...
End Sub
Private Sub cliente_nome_Change()
    '...
End Sub
Private Sub Label1_Click()
    '...
End Sub
Private Sub Label2_Click()
    '...
End Sub
```

Comment: Please copy and paste your code into your question (as you have) but after pasting, highlight the code/text and click the `{}` button in the editor to preserve whitespace and formatting.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Allow me this hint as new contributor: Please *edit* the question to a) limit it to a *specific* problem and b) to show enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. - See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question and [How to create a **M**inimal, **C**omplete, and **V**erifiable (reproducable) example - MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) @Francis